# A few questions about electric field and equipotential lines of parallel plates with widening ends

Tags: electricity, electric-fields

I'm a second grade physics student and I take Electricity and Magnetism course and I have laboratory class. Due to pandemic I can't go to laboratory and find out the answers of my questions by using the equipments in my university so I need to use internet and research about my questions. Unfortunately I couldn't find enough information on internet about my questions so I'm here asking my questions.

I was doing a lab experiment about parallel plates in 2 dimension but the plates are not straight at all.

[image: Circuit of the lab experiment]

You can see the circuit of the lab experiment on the above diagram. Distance between plates is $a=8cm$ and length of straight part of each plate is $b=10cm$.

[image: Teledeltos paper used in circuit]

[image: The lab experiment circuit]

On the next image, you can see the teledeltos paper used in lab experiment circuit. We painted our parallel plates using silver paint. We give $V_0=9V$ of voltage using our D.C. power supply.

We calculated the electrical potential difference of each dot in on the milimetric paper using voltmetre and noted next to each dot as in the following image. Each dot is seperated with $1cm$ distances.

[image: Voltage values of dots on milimetric paper]

We only used voltage values of points on the middle line ($V_1$) and the line $1cm$ above the middle line ($V_2$). Using these values I filled the table below.

[image: Table]

### My questions

1. How electric field is created using this circuit? We connect tip of each plate to our circuit using conducting wires and thus there is a current on plates but I can not understand what is happening behind the scene when we set our D.C. power supply to 9V. Could u explain how does the electric field created?
2. Magnitude of the electic field created by parallel plates is calculated using $E=\frac{V_0}{a}=\frac{9V}{0,08m}=112,5 V/m$. We drawed equipotential lines with 1cm distance between each of them. So we can calculate the electrical potential difference between each equipotential line using $\Delta V=E\Delta z=112,5 V/m\cdot 0,01m=1,125V$. But if we consider the $\Delta V$ values calcuted on the expiermental circuted the valeus of $\Delta V$ varies between $0,3V$ and $0,1V$ which is not close to $1,125V$. Could you explain me why there is a difference like that?
3. What does the total of $\Sigma E_{ort}\Delta y$ values on the last column tell us about? (ort. means avg. by the way) This total value has some relation with experiment background information.

[image: Introduction information of experiment]

My lecturer in lab told me that the total of last column values ($E\Delta y$) in range of $y=[0cm, 10cm]$ should equal to $\Phi=\int{E_z dy}=V_0\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)=9V\frac{0,10m}{0,08m}11,25V$. What does this value mean?

Thanks!

Comment: If one voltmeter lead was connected to the centre-tap of the battery, as you show on your top diagram, then when the other lead is placed anywhere on the mid-line between the plates, the voltmeter ought to read zero, or close to zero. I don't understand how it can be roughly 8V, when there is 9 V between the plates.

Comment: @PhilipWood Actually the original diagram was different but I thought that it's wrong so I edited it. You can check the original one: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o20g9H7RO9s9vZSEvqrJcxNTSX3yFzRZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I couldn't see much difference between the new diagram and the old. I remain puzzled. As you go from the centre-tap on the battery to its + terminal the potential goes up by 4.5 V. As you go from the positive plate to the negative via the teledeltos paper, the potential goes down by 9 V (the battery voltage). So midway between the plates you have gone down by 4.5 V from the top plate, so in potential terms you are level with the centre-tap on the battery. So the voltmeter ought to read zero.

Comment: I think that there's something badly wrong with your set-up. I wonder whether the teledeltos paper is worn out; I mean that it might have lost its conductivity along lines where the surface has been damaged. On a separate theme, I find your textbook extract hard to follow. For example, in equation (2), where has that V come from?

Comment: @PhilipWood hey! Thanks for thinking about my problem. I was waiting for my lecturer's response to my e-mail this weekend and she responded just before 30 minutes ago. She told that the teledeltos paper is worn out and they haven't renewed the silver paint on it so the it might lost its conductivity, as you guessed. I also explained my other 2 questions to her with short 3 paragraphs but she was a little annoyed about my e-mail and said that "it's boring to answer that long questions". Anyways, I'm a little sad of her reply. The second equation's integral variable must be $dy$ instead of $dt$.

Comment: @PhilipWood $J=\int{F_z dt}=\int{-e E_z dt}=-e\int{E_z \frac{1}{v}\frac{dy}{dt}dt}=-\frac{e}{v}\int{E_z dy}$ and $V$ in the equation (2) is speed of electron in y-axis. There were a mistake on clipped part of textbook. Thanks for informing me about it.

Comment: That's beginning to make sense. Thanks for reporting back. I expect you know, incidentally, that the deflection plates in a cathode ray tube are flared (made further apart at the ends) so that the electron beam doesn't hit them on its way to the screen.

Comment: @PhilipWood You are welcome. Yes, I know what's the main idea of widening ends of plates.